# How can I manage docker group in freeipa?

Tags: centos, docker, group, freeipa

First I tried managing dockerroot in freeipa, since that is the only one I saw with `sudo getent group | grep dock`.

I saw somewhere that said I can create a group in freeipa with the same GID and it will sync with the local group.

That is not an option for me. I have the group `dockerroot` on several machines with *different* GIDs.

So I turned to `sss_override`.

I tried `sudo sss_override group-add dockerroot -g <my_freeipa_gid>` but I get:

```
Unable to find group dockerroot@[unknown].
```

I can't find in the documentation if I am missing something. I tried using `dockerroot@localhost` but I get:

```
Unable to parse name dockerroot@localhost.
```

I started deploying docker to machines and want a couple users to be able to run docker without sudo. I don't want to create rules on every target machine. Any time I spin up a new machine with docker, special users should automatically get the group membership through freeipa rules.

Doing `yum remove docker && yum install docker` doesn't seem to affect the group either.

Could I just delete it and recreate it? I don't know what I'm breaking here so I'm hesitant to do more.

---

Now I've tried following docker's docs which say to do this:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
docker run hello-world
```

I want this on my domain so instead I create the group in freeipa, and add my user to it.
I gave it time to sync, logged out and in, and checked the group:

```
sudo getent group docker
docker:*:<my_freeipa_id>:<my_uid>
```

But I still get permission denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the group `dockerroot`, I am assuming you are using the RedHat/CentOS provided Docker packages.

I believe the issue is that RedHat does not ship Docker to be used by groups by default.  To verify, check the permissions of the socket file (default location `/var/run/docker.sock`).

You would need to change the Docker configuration (default `/etc/docker/daemon.json`) to create the Docker socket with the group permissions you wish to use.  You can use any group, as long as the socket file is created with the desired group permissions.  [Official documentation for the daemon.json config file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)

[This Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1214104) has a statement about why the default permissions do not allow non-root groups to run Docker

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer. I tried using `{ "group": "docker" }` but that doesn't seem to give me privileges. I think I am going to give up on this and look for other solutions around sudo.